# How to launch my app from share menu of another app in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to add my app in the "share" menu that comes when you try to attach an image in whats app or any other chat app. I just cant seem to figure this out. I want something like this:-

[image]

This is in what's app when i try to attach a picture, i click on "Gallery". It takes me to gallery and then in the share menu, I want my app to be present their..

[image]

I have tried putting these intent filters in my manifest but they don't seem to be working.

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

My app has pictures that can be attached in chat but i don't know why it doesn't show up in the menu. Please help

my manifest:-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfragments"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <activity android:name=".TabActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you post the entire manifest?

Comment: All looks fine from what I can see

Comment: is there anything else that i need to do to get my app in share menu... I don't get it.. any other suggestions?

Comment: apparently if i use " */* " instead of image/* in GET_CONTENT filter.. its showing up in the menu... thats odd as my app only has images

Answer (score 1):

heyy you can use **Quick Menu** for giving that menu option. Quick menu provide  horizontal and vertical both option with image view.  or u have to make your custom.